How to insert a DEFAULT custom header value to all Mock SoapUI REST projects?
I have SoapUI (Open Source Edition) installed on a windows. To test my REST project my frontend send the data to Mock SoapUI and to avoid the CORS issue I need put in the actions 3 headers manualy to each possibility ex /users GET, /users PUT etc.
There a way to put automaticly headers for all mock actions?
I only find a solution to SOAP and to payed version.
Below how I am doing now, each action need these headers, I wanto for all project:


Can you please add what you tried and where is it possibly failing? any errors?

I put a image how I do now, but I want configure for all project because add for each action is a lot of work
